# AWS Rekognition -- How to Parse All the Text in an Image?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am trying to parse text in an image of a restaurant bill. I've been able to set up the ruby AWS  SDK which has the Rekognition client using [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/images-bytes.html). Moreover, locally I have been able to make a call to Rekognition, passing an image locally.

When I make the call with `#detect_text` ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Rekognition/Client.html#detect_text-instance_method)), I get a response and the response has `TextDetections` which represent either lines or words in the image. I would like however that response to only contain `TextDetections` of type `LINE`. Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to get a response back that only contains `TextDetections` of type `LINE`?
2. Is it possible to increase the limit of words detected in an image? Apparently according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_DetectText.html):

> DetectText can detect up to 50 words in an image
>   That sounds like a hard limit to me.

3. Is there a way I can get around the limit of 50 words in an image? Perhaps I can make multiple calls on the same image where Rekognition can parse the same image multiple times until it has all the words?

Comment: From my knowledge: No you can't limit the response, No you can't increase the limit, No, but cropping and parsing multiple times is a common method used. You might be better-off using an OCR library rather than Rekognition, since Rekognition's primary purpose is detecting objects rather than text.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You cannot detect more than 50 words in an image. A workaround is to crop the image into multiple images, and run DetectText on each cropped image.